# How to store dynamic values in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I need to store some events inside a Cassandra Table. I had  working a lot with habse and I am new to the cassandra data modeling.

the events are identifyed by a type and they have some attributes. the attributes don't have a fixed type and potentially they don't have a fixed lenght.

The JSON that describe an event:

```
{
   obj_id: <identify the object that the event is related>
   timestamp: <timestamp of the event>
   type: <type of the event>
   attributes: {
       attribute1: value
       attribute2: value
       ......
   }
}
```

The query should extract all events of a specific type with related attributes.

I have figured out two scenarios:

1. Store attributes as Json (type text). I will deserialize them on extraction
2. Store attributes as `Map<String,Byte>`. I will deserialize the type on extraction

I don't know which pick of the two scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

you can have a `map<text, blob>` `attributes` in your table if you want a simple 1:1 to your object. I would recommend considering how your going to query your data and model around that however. That said if you are just using this as a single object store and retrieval it can be as simple as:

```
CREATE TABLE object (
  obj_id text PRIMARY KEY,
  created timestamp,
  type text,
  attributes map<text, blob>
);
```